# How to have the whole of my string containing apostrophes sent to my function?

Tags: javascript

```
function getNameAndPath(data) {
return "<div onclick='OpenFile(\"" + data.Path + "\")'> <b>" + data.Name+ "</b></div>"}
```

I tried this, but because of the apostrophe contained in my variable data.Path it returns to me this:

[image]

The function is called to display data from a Datatable

```
  {
            "data": getNameAndPath,
            "name": "Nom",
            "width": "auto",
        },
```

Comment: Can you show where `getNameAndPath` is being called and the return value is being inserted into the HTML?

Comment: I modified the post to see where I call the method

Comment: I found solution to my problem using regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a string, return an *element*, and call `addEventListener` on the element. This lets you use the `data` parameter in a closure, without the escaping problems of inline attributes (which should be avoided whenever possible, because they're hard to manage, and what you're experiencing is one reason why - they have string escaping issues and scoping issues):

```
function getNameAndPath(data) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `<b>${data.Name}</b>`;
  div.addEventListener('click', () => OpenFile(data.Path));
  return div;
}
```

Then insert the element into the HTML with something like

```
container.appendChild(getNameAndPath(data));
```

This inserts the `data.Name` property directly into the HTML though, which usually isn't desirable - if the data is untrustworthy, it'll allow arbitrary Javascript to be executed, and can lead to issues with characters with special meanings in HTML. If those can be issues for you, assign to the `textContent` of the `<b>` element instead:

```
function getNameAndPath(data) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const b = div.appendChild(document.createElement('b'));
  b.textContent = data.Name;
  div.addEventListener('click', () => OpenFile(data.Path));
  return div;
}
```

If you can't control how `getNameAndPath` is being called, then the proper way to do this while avoiding inline attribute listeners would be to add a click listener to the container, while having a way to associate each element with its path. For example, after populating the table with

```
function getNameAndPath(data) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const b = div.appendChild(document.createElement('b'));
  b.textContent = data.Name;
  div.dataset.Path = data.Path;
  return div;
}
```

then add a click listener:

```
table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const div = e.target.closest('[data-path]');
  if (div) {
    OpenFile(div.dataset.path);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `` **(template strings)**.

```
function getNameAndPath(data) {
   return `<div onclick='OpenFile(\${data.Path}\)'> <b>${data.Name}</b></div>`
}
```

Comment: It shows me characters that I do not want ("+ var +") and there are always problems with single quotes

Comment: @Dynamo there is no need to write + for concatenation in template strings. Answer edited

Comment: Ok I changed but I have the same problem of apostrophe for the path : <div onclick="OpenFile(" essais="" et="" prototypes\protoypes\modes="" operatoire\mode="" operatoire="" presse="" hydraulique="" proto.docx')'=""> <b>Mode Operatoire Presse Hydraulique Proto</b></div>

Comment: here also you have to use template strings. Do read it from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals